# Recognizing passed parameters in a CALL instruction using Ollydbg

Tags: ollydbg

The calling convention used in assembly differs depending to the compiler. The Question is:
How ollydbg2.01 would help me to recognize the parameters passed from caller to the callee and values returned back to the caller from the callee for a CALL instruction.
The assembly which I am working on is compiled by Microsoft visual C++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling convention is `not dependent` on any compiler.

By `default` microsoft visual studio uses `__cdecl` (user has to clean up the stack)

You can force it to use `__stdcall` (called function is responsible for cleaning the stack)

You can also compile with `__declspec (naked)` ( arbitrary cleanup )

Afaik x64 is FASTCALL only (no other calling conventions are applicable)

you can recognize calling convention by looking at the assembly

if you observe

```
call xxxx
add esp,XXXXX 
it most likely is __cdecl
```

if you observe

```
call xxxx
inside the call 
leave 
retn XXX then it is likely to be __stdcall
```

and so on

you may need to recognize a specific construct by observation of disassembly and corelate it with the calling convention

calling conventions can also be mixed arbitrarily so you may need to ascertain each function calls individually

**compile with cl /Zi /nologo /W4 /analyze xxx.cpp /link /RELEASE**

```
#include <stdio.h>
char *domain = "i am calling me" , *formatstr = "%s %s\n";
void __cdecl cdecprint (char *king) {
    printf(formatstr,domain,king);
}
void __stdcall stdprint (char *king) {
    printf(formatstr,domain,king);
}
void __fastcall fastprint (char *king) {
    printf(formatstr,domain,king);
}
__declspec(naked) void arbitprint (char *king) {
    (void)king; //unreferenced warning 
    __asm    {
        lea eax, [esp+4]
        push [eax]
        push domain
            push formatstr
            call printf
            add esp,0Ch
            retn
    }
}
int main (void) {
    cdecprint("cdecinking");
    stdprint("stdking");
    fastprint("fastking");
    arbitprint("arbitking");
    return 0x1337;
}
```

and the relevent disassembly of main

```
004010A0 callme.main PUSH    EBP                     ; {
004010A1             MOV     EBP, ESP
004010A3             PUSH    callme.004121A4     ; cdecprint("cdecinking");
004010A8             CALL    callme.cdecprint
004010AD             ADD     ESP, 4  <---------- ; call above is likely __cdecl
004010B0             PUSH    callme.004121B0     ; stdprint("stdking");
004010B5             CALL    callme.stdprint  <--; no cleanup likely __stdcall
004010BA             MOV     ECX, callme.004121B8; fastprint("fastking"); 
004010BF             CALL    callme.fastprint <--; __stdcall ? No __fastcall 
004010C4             PUSH    callme.004121C4     ; arbitprint("arbitking");
004010C9             CALL    callme.arbitprint   ;
004010CE             ADD     ESP, 4  <---------  ; __cdecl? No __declspec (naked)
004010D1             MOV     EAX, 1337           ; return 0x1337;
004010D6             POP     EBP                 ; }
004010D7             RETN
```

**__cdecl**

```
00401000 callme.cdecprint  PUSH    EBP
00401001                   MOV     EBP, ESP
00401003                   MOV     EAX, DWORD PTR SS:[EBP+8]
00401006                   PUSH    EAX
00401007                   MOV     ECX, DWORD PTR DS:[domain]
0040100D                   PUSH    ECX
0040100E                   MOV     EDX, DWORD PTR DS:[formatstr]
00401014                   PUSH    EDX
00401015                   CALL    callme.printf
0040101A                   ADD     ESP, 0C
0040101D                   POP     EBP
0040101E                   RETN
```

**__stdcall**

```
00401020 callme.stdprint   PUSH    EBP
00401021                   MOV     EBP, ESP
00401023                   MOV     EAX, DWORD PTR SS:[EBP+8]
00401026                   PUSH    EAX
00401027                   MOV     ECX, DWORD PTR DS:[domain]
0040102D                   PUSH    ECX
0040102E                   MOV     EDX, DWORD PTR DS:[formatstr]
00401034                   PUSH    EDX
00401035                   CALL    callme.printf
0040103A                   ADD     ESP, 0C
0040103D                   POP     EBP
0040103E                   RETN    4
```

**__fastcall**

```
00401050 callme.fastprint  PUSH    EBP     
00401051                   MOV     EBP, ESP
00401053                   PUSH    ECX
00401054                   MOV     DWORD PTR SS:[EBP-4], ECX
00401057                   MOV     EAX, DWORD PTR SS:[EBP-4]
0040105A                   PUSH    EAX
0040105B                   MOV     ECX, DWORD PTR DS:[domain]
00401061                   PUSH    ECX
00401062                   MOV     EDX, DWORD PTR DS:[formatstr]
00401068                   PUSH    EDX
00401069                   CALL    callme.printf
0040106E                   ADD     ESP, 0C
00401071                   MOV     ESP, EBP
00401073                   POP     EBP
00401074                   RETN
```

**__declspec (naked)**

```
00401080 callme.arbitprint LEA     EAX, DWORD PTR SS:[ESP+4]
00401084                   PUSH    DWORD PTR DS:[EAX]
00401086                   PUSH    DWORD PTR DS:[domain]
0040108C                   PUSH    DWORD PTR DS:[formatstr]
00401092                   CALL    callme.printf
00401097                   ADD     ESP, 0C
0040109A                   RETN
```

apart from the 4 above there are a few specialized calling conventions 
and obsolete calling conventions

```
__clrcall is for managed 
__vectorcall is for using streaming instructions (sse 2 .....)
__thiscall used mostly oop and com methods
__pascal etc obsolete
```